# Listbox Data Binding Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

windows phone 8 `ListBox` binding with list of items

```
listbox.Datacontext = List;
```

but still got nothing.

Comment: Probably because you have no idea how binding works.  Step back and learn about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
listbox.ItemsSource = List;
```

Answer (score 0):

`listbox.ItemSource = List;`

it will directly bind the data

if you use

`listbox.Datacontext = List;`
you should mention the binding in xaml like this

`<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListBox>`